# caassandra : multiple condition on same column

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

create table :

```
CREATE TABLE notifications (
  id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id bigint,
  received_datetime timestamp,
  );
```

cqlsh :

```
select count(*)
  from notifications
  where received_datetime >='2016-10-11 00:00:00'
    and received_datetime >='2016-10-18 00:00:00'
  ALLOW FILTERING;
```

error got :-

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="More than one restriction was found for the start bound on received_datetime"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you actually want is the following query:

```
select count(*) from notifications
    where received_datetime >='2016-10-11 00:00:00' 
    and received_datetime <='2016-10-18 00:00:00' 
    ALLOW FILTERING;
```

Otherwise you can merge two lower bound conditions into one by picking the more restrictive of them:

```
select count(*) from notifications
    where received_datetime >= '2016-10-18 00:00:00'
    ALLOW FILTERING;
```

Comment: The query you are doing above with the ALLOW FILTERING is an anti-pattern in Cassandra.  This will cause a scatter gather operation across the entire cluster which will be horribly slow and will most likely time out with any reasonably large amount of data.  You should change your table structure to satisfy the query you are asking it.   This means setting up a different Partition and Primary Key to answer this query unless you know the id in which case you can just add received_datetime as a clustering column and perform a range query on it.